# How should i write needed constructor for class which includes dynamic array?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Seniors!
I've been stucked on this topic and can`t find the way to write follow constructors(and methods) for both classes **K1** and **K2**:

- default constructor
- copying constructor and rewriting method.
- correct overloading operator << for K2

```
    class K1 {
    string* p1; // p1 in future should be dynamic array
public:
    K1() : p1(new string) {}; // my version of def. constructor
    ~K1() { delete p1; }; // destructor
    K1(const K1& k) : p1(new string(*k.p1)) {}; // my version of copying constructor
    K1& operator= (const K1& copy) { // rewriting method in my vision
        *p1 = *copy.p1;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

```
class K2 {
    K1 p1;
    double p2;
public: 
    K2(const string & one, const string & two, const double & price) // mostly stucked here: how can i reforward data from here to K1`s pointer (which is an array)
};
```

```
int main() {
    K2 ob1, ob2; // testing code
    const K2* wsk1 = new K2("kawa", "z mlekiem", 4.50);
    const K2 ob3(*wsk1);
    delete wsk1;
    K2* wsk2 = new K2(ob3);
    ob2 = *wsk2;
    cout << ob3;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help, guys!

Comment: And what is the problem? What doesn't work so far? Compilation error? Runtime error? Something undesireable outcome? State a particular problem. Aside from that, you make your life way easier if you'd use proper containers, in your case probably `std::vector<std::string> p1;`. Also, any usage of `new` is potential errors to happen (not in your code as it is, but at some point in the future, it will), try to use it as little as possible by instead use containers and smart pointers (like `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: Also, try to use descriptive names. We have no idea what K1 and K2 are supposed to be and what goal you try to achieve. If they'd have names like Student or ComplexNumber, we could give better advice. Same goes for members and variables.

Comment: *"`string* p1; // p1 in future should be dynamic array`"*, so `std::vector<std::string>` and rule of 0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

add constructor for K1

```
K1(const string& s) : p1(new string(s)){};
```

then in K2

```
K2(const string & one, const string & two, const double & price) : p1(one){}
```